# C# unity convert iterated number to a ranged number based on number of clicks

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, iteration

I'm trying to get a number between 0 and 3. I am trying to iterate through a counter and every 5 clicks on a button, it calls a method, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried various ways to do it. If I could get some hints on how to complete this then please let me know. If you need any other info then also let me know. Thanks!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class ButtonClick : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 starPos;
    private int starCounter;
    private int[] starTypes;
    private int totalStarTypes = 4;

    public Button button;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text starCounterText;

    private Image starImage;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        starTypes = new int[totalStarTypes];
    }

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            starCounter++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < starCounter; i++) {
            int j = i;
            int type = (j % 5);
            if (type == 0) {
                //SpawnStar (j%5);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void UpdateStar () {
        starCounterText.text = "Star Counter: " + starCounter;
    }

    public void SpawnStar(int type){
        if (type == 0) {
            Debug.Log ("White Star Spawned!");
        }
        if (type == 1) {
            Debug.Log ("Red Star Spawned!");
        }
        if (type == 2) {
            Debug.Log ("Yellow Star Spawned!");
        }
        if (type == 3) {
            Debug.Log ("Blue Star Spawned!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What determines which star spawns? Is it iterative as well? Random? Some other determining factor?

Comment: For every click a counter is added by 1 (already handled) and for every 5 clicks it spawns a star. So whatever integer handles the 5th click logic (like j or type perhaps, still haven't worked it out) it calls the function to spawn a type (int) of star. Also I will add random into it once I get the basics done.For now just the iteration over the counter in which the logic is handled determines which type of star is spawned. Maybe I should use like a List, iterate through the list and get a random int out of that?

Comment: You don't need lists, arrays, or loops. This can be done with simple math. Remember the KISS principle.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new Random();

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        starCounter = (starCounter + 1) % 5;
        if (starCounter == 0) SpawnStar(r.Next(0, 4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code will spawn the all stars every frame after the 5'th click.

Try this, it will spawn a single star when you click, and only the one you wanted to spawn.

- The int `starCounter` will handle which star to spawn
- The bool `executeSpawn` will handle when to spawn a star

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class ButtonClick : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 starPos;
    private int starCounter;
    private bool executeSpawn;
    private int[] starTypes;
    private int totalStarTypes = 4;

    public Button button;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text starCounterText;

    private Image starImage;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        starTypes = new int[totalStarTypes];
    }

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            starCounter++;
            executeSpawn = true;
        }

        if(executeSpawn) {
            SpawnStar (i % 5);
            executeSpawn = false;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void UpdateStar () {
        starCounterText.text = "Star Counter: " + starCounter;
    }

    public void SpawnStar(int type){
        if (type == 0) {
            Debug.Log ("White Star Spawned!");
        }
        if (type == 1) {
            Debug.Log ("Red Star Spawned!");
        }
        if (type == 2) {
            Debug.Log ("Yellow Star Spawned!");
        }
        if (type == 3) {
            Debug.Log ("Blue Star Spawned!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, looking at what the `SpawnStar` function does, it would seem that is what is required. I will edit the answer to reflect this

Comment: First, OP specifically states that a star should appear every 5th click. Second, this code can call `SpawnStar` with a parameter 4 which will do nothing. Third, if the goal *were* to spawn a star on every click, the boolean flag is redundant.